# Handling variadic arguments function calls in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variadic-functions

I have made some helper functions that run a simulation using a lot of functions inside them.

In order to make these helper functions more user friendly I want to give the user the choice of calling the functions with fewer arguments (the arguments that are not passed into the function are assigned a predefined value).

For example if I have a function

```
function [res, val, h, v, u] = compute(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
    if nargin < 4 || isempty(arg4) arg4 = 150; end
```

and the function runsim which is defined like this

```
function [res, val, h, v, u] = runsim(v, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

the silly way to do it is

```
if nargin < 5 || isempty(arg4)
    compute(arg1, arg2, arg3)
else
    compute(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
end
```

Another solution would be to change the arguments to vectors but I am not allowed to touch the functions behind the simulation. Is there a Matlab way to handle this situation or do I have to write the same code again and again with fewer arguments?

Comment: Do you mean that you can't change "*compute*"?

Comment: @Andrey Yes that's what I mean.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pack and unpack function arguments using cell arrays:

```
a={'foo','bar',42}
fun(a{:}) % is the same as:
fun('foo','bar',42)
```

The same goes for output arguments:

```
a,b,c=fun(); % or easier:
c=cell(3,1);
[c{:}]=fun();
```

Since varargin is also a cell array, you can just pop the field the function you want to execute is in, and then pass the rest of the fields as arguments to the function.

Comment: I liked it and it worked. Now I am just adding or removing arguments and I do a single call.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is to use [`varagin`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/varargin.html). For example, to define a function which takes one required argument and four optional arguments we could do something like

```
function [res, val, h, v, u] = runsim(v, varagin)

    % Check that at least 1 and at most 5 input arguments were passed
    error(nargchk(1, 5, nargin))

    % Check number of optional arguments passed
    noptargin = size(varargin, 2)

    % Check how many arguments passed, set default values if required.
    % Im sure the following could be cleaned up.
    if noptargin == 1
        arg1 = varagin{1}
        arg2 = ...
        arg3 = ...
        arg4 = ...
    elseif noptargin == 2
        arg1 = varagin{1}
        arg2 = varagin{2}
        arg3 = ...
        arg4 = ...
    elseif noptargin == 3
        arg1 = varagin{1}
        arg2 = varagin{2}
        arg3 = varagin{3}
        arg4 = ...
    end

    % Finally, call compute with all arguments set
    compute(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)

end
```

**Edit**: An alternative way would be to use [`inputParser`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/inputparserclass.html) in your `runsim` function.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with @Chris, though I want to introduce a slight variation.
If what you meant is that you can't change **compute()**, then you can use **varargin**, and the **Name/Value** idiom.

*(In order to run this code, you must download the catstruct() function from [Matlab central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7842))*

```
function runsim( varargin) 
      partialParams= struct(varargin{:});
      % Check each variable 
      DefaultVal1 = 1;
      DefaultVal2 = 2;
      defaultParams = struct('Param1',DefaultVal1,'Param2',DefaultVal2');
      % Merge 2 structs
      params = catstruct(defaultParams,partialParams);
      % Call compute on the parameters.
      fnames = fieldnames(params);
      vals = {};
      for i=1:numel(fnames)
            vals{end+1} = params.(fnames{i});
      end
      compute( vals{:});
 end
```

And the calling function:

```
 runsim('Param1',Value1,'Param2',Value2);
 runsim('Param2',Value2);
 runsim('Param1',Value1);
```